# fetch json data in spring boot rest api

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

```
{
   "name": "ssf",
   "attribute_type": "Compound",
   "is_included": 1,
   "subAttributes": [
      {
         "name": "dtfg",
         "sub_data_type": "string",
         "sub_dateFormat": "",
         "sub_numericFormat": "",
         "sub_stringFormat": "dxcf",
         "subDataLength": "56",
         "subMatchType": "direct",
         "subCheckLevenshtein": false,
         "subCheckJaroWinkler": false,
         "subCheckHammingDistance": false,
         "subCheckMongeElkan": false,
         "sub_formula": "",
         "id": "p_id"
      },
      {
         "name": "rsdxcfgvjbh",
         "sub_data_type": "date",
         "sub_dateFormat": "mm_dd_yyyy",
         "sub_numericFormat": "",
         "sub_stringFormat": "",
         "subDataLength": "45",
         "subMatchType": "direct",
         "subCheckLevenshtein": false,
         "subCheckJaroWinkler": false,
         "subCheckHammingDistance": false,
         "subCheckMongeElkan": false,
         "sub_formula": "",
         "id": "p_id"
      }
   ]
}
```

Hi I am writting rest api in spring boot java. From post-man I'm sending nested json and want to save data in mysql database using jdbc prepared statement .. Please tell me how can I print this nested json of subattributes using for loop and others.

Comment: could you add sample code that you tried so far?

Comment: PreparedStatement st=con.prepareStatement(query);
    st.setString(1, name);
    st.setString(2, attribute_type);
    System.out.println(name);
    System.out.println(attribute_type);
    int i=st.executeUpdate();  
             System.out.println(i);

Comment: right now i am not able to acesss subattributes of array type .

Comment: @RequestMapping(value = "/api/matchingAttribute", method = RequestMethod.POST,headers={"Accept=*/*","content-type=application/json"})
 public String NewMatchingAttribute(@RequestBody MatchingAttribute matchingAttribute) throws SQLException
 {
  DbConnection ObjdbInit = new DbConnection();
  Connection con=ObjdbInit.dbConnection();

Answer (score 0):

Below is your pojo class according to your json. now you need to just fire your JDBC query after assignining that pojo class elements. hope this will be helpful

```
public class SampleClass
{
 private String name;

 private String is_included;

 private String attribute_type;

 private SubAttributes[] subAttributes;

public String getName ()
{
    return name;
}

public void setName (String name)
{
    this.name = name;
}

public String getIs_included ()
{
    return is_included;
}

public void setIs_included (String is_included)
{
    this.is_included = is_included;
}

public String getAttribute_type ()
{
    return attribute_type;
}

public void setAttribute_type (String attribute_type)
{
    this.attribute_type = attribute_type;
}

public SubAttributes[] getSubAttributes ()
{
    return subAttributes;
}

public void setSubAttributes (SubAttributes[] subAttributes)
{
    this.subAttributes = subAttributes;
}

@Override
public String toString()
{
    return "ClassPojo [name = "+name+", is_included = "+is_included+", attribute_type = "+attribute_type+", subAttributes = "+subAttributes+"]";
}
}


public class SubAttributes
{
private String sub_formula;

private String subCheckHammingDistance;

private String subCheckLevenshtein;

private String subCheckJaroWinkler;

private String subCheckMongeElkan;

private String sub_dateFormat;

private String sub_data_type;

private String subMatchType;

private String id;

private String sub_stringFormat;

private String sub_numericFormat;

private String subDataLength;

private String name;

public String getSub_formula ()
{
    return sub_formula;
}

public void setSub_formula (String sub_formula)
{
    this.sub_formula = sub_formula;
}

public String getSubCheckHammingDistance ()
{
    return subCheckHammingDistance;
}

public void setSubCheckHammingDistance (String subCheckHammingDistance)
{
    this.subCheckHammingDistance = subCheckHammingDistance;
}

public String getSubCheckLevenshtein ()
{
    return subCheckLevenshtein;
}

public void setSubCheckLevenshtein (String subCheckLevenshtein)
{
    this.subCheckLevenshtein = subCheckLevenshtein;
}

public String getSubCheckJaroWinkler ()
{
    return subCheckJaroWinkler;
}

public void setSubCheckJaroWinkler (String subCheckJaroWinkler)
{
    this.subCheckJaroWinkler = subCheckJaroWinkler;
}

public String getSubCheckMongeElkan ()
{
    return subCheckMongeElkan;
}

public void setSubCheckMongeElkan (String subCheckMongeElkan)
{
    this.subCheckMongeElkan = subCheckMongeElkan;
}

public String getSub_dateFormat ()
{
    return sub_dateFormat;
}

public void setSub_dateFormat (String sub_dateFormat)
{
    this.sub_dateFormat = sub_dateFormat;
}

public String getSub_data_type ()
{
    return sub_data_type;
}

public void setSub_data_type (String sub_data_type)
{
    this.sub_data_type = sub_data_type;
}

public String getSubMatchType ()
{
    return subMatchType;
}

public void setSubMatchType (String subMatchType)
{
    this.subMatchType = subMatchType;
}

public String getId ()
{
    return id;
}

public void setId (String id)
{
    this.id = id;
}

public String getSub_stringFormat ()
{
    return sub_stringFormat;
}

public void setSub_stringFormat (String sub_stringFormat)
{
    this.sub_stringFormat = sub_stringFormat;
}

public String getSub_numericFormat ()
{
    return sub_numericFormat;
}

public void setSub_numericFormat (String sub_numericFormat)
{
    this.sub_numericFormat = sub_numericFormat;
}

public String getSubDataLength ()
{
    return subDataLength;
}

public void setSubDataLength (String subDataLength)
{
    this.subDataLength = subDataLength;
}

public String getName ()
{
    return name;
}

public void setName (String name)
{
    this.name = name;
}

@Override
public String toString()
{
    return "ClassPojo [sub_formula = "+sub_formula+", subCheckHammingDistance = "+subCheckHammingDistance+", subCheckLevenshtein = "+subCheckLevenshtein+", subCheckJaroWinkler = "+subCheckJaroWinkler+", subCheckMongeElkan = "+subCheckMongeElkan+", sub_dateFormat = "+sub_dateFormat+", sub_data_type = "+sub_data_type+", subMatchType = "+subMatchType+", id = "+id+", sub_stringFormat = "+sub_stringFormat+", sub_numericFormat = "+sub_numericFormat+", subDataLength = "+subDataLength+", name = "+name+"]";
}
 }
```